# Every integer in the form $(6m + 1)(12m + 1)(18m + 1)$, is a carmichael number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

> **Question:** Show that every integer of the form $(6m + 1)(12m + 1)(18m + 1)$, where m is a positive integer such that $6m + 1$, $12m + 1$, and $18m + 1$ are all primes, is a Carmichael Number

I know that $(6m + 1)(12m + 1)(18m + 1)$ is probably the most widely known form of Carmichael numbers but I'm not entirely sure how to go about proving it for *every* integer of the form. I was going to write out the proof with the assumption m is prime but going back to reread the question, it seems that m is just a positive integer with no mention of it being prime. Would I factor out the m and write it out from there? Or is there a theorem that I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Korselt's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Korselt's_criterion) says that $n$ is a Carmichael number if and only if $n$ is squarefree, and for every prime $p|n$, we also have $(p-1)|(n-1)$.

For the sample integer, $n=pqr$, where $p=6m+1, q=12m+1, r=18m+1$ are all prime by hypothesis.  $n$ is squarefree, being the product of three distinct primes. We calculate and simplify $$n-1=36m(36m^2+11m+1)$$ Hence, each of $p-1, q-1, r-1$ divide $n-1$.